# How does Cucumber handle a list of non-parameterised strings with pipe characters in feature file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a scenario where I used pipe characters to introduce a list of items for a better readability:

```
Scenario: Search users
    Then I should see the user list with the following columns:
      | Name   |
      | Age    |
      | DOB    |
      | Address|
```

The items in the list are non-parameterised, so the scenario will only run once.

I created the step definition for the step like this:

```
@Then("I should see the user list with the following columns:")
```

On execution, the test was not found and I got the error: `io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException: Failed to parse resource at: classpath:features`

If I remove pipe characters and condense the list like this, then the test works fine:

```
Then I should see the user list with the following columns: Name, Age, DOB, Address
```

I am not sure how step definitions handle a step with a list of non-parameterised items having pipe characters, without cucumber thinking the step has a parameter

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Did my answer answered your question?

Comment: @hfontanez, I am still implementing it. The answer is helpful so far

Comment: If you have any other questions, let me know. I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: At a glance the syntax looks correct. Maybe add a space in between `Address|`.

Answer (score 1):

The first convention

```
Then I should see the user list with the following columns:
  | Name   |
  | Age    |
  | DOB    |
  | Address|
```

resembles a scenario with at data table as parameters. For this to work, your step definition method must have a `DataTable` argument.

```
@Given ("I should see the user list with the following columns:")
public void verifyUserList(DataTable table) {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Depending on the table, you will have to convert it to some kind of list. A single column list like the one here, should convert to `List<String>`. A row with multiple columns should convert to a `<List<List<String>>`. It is up to you to code the conversion correctly. A quick search on *Cucumber Data Tables* should help you code this correctly.

Another similar convention is *Scenario Outline*. For scenario outlines to be valid, the test must be tagged with `Scenario Outline` and the table with `Examples`. For instance:

```
Scenario: Search users
    Then I should see the user list with the following columns:
      | col1   | col2  | col3  |  col4   |
      | Name   | Age   | DOB   | Address |
```

The examples table should contain at least two rows: the top row for the variable names, and the second and subsequent rows for the values. So, if you want to check the column names for 5 database tables, you will have 5 rows of values and each row will be processed in its own test run. For this case, the step definition should look something like this:

```
@Given ("I should see the user list with the following columns: <col1> <col2> <col3> <col4>")
public void verifyUserList(String col1, String col2, String col3, String col4) {
    // Your logic here
}
```

The name of the variables don't need to match the identifiers inside the angular braces. However, they must match the column headers on the examples table.

The last convention, is a single test step with four values. In this case, value is substituted in the step definition during a single test run.

Basically, each format has distinct requirements. Now, to answer why the first one didn't work, it should all boil down to the method mapped to the Cucumber step. My guess is that it doesn't contain a data table as an argument.